# glibc rand() doesn't work with python but works fine in online compiler

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm trying to embed a glibc rand() function into python. My purpose is to predict the next values of rand() basing on the assumption that is uses an LCG. I've read that it only uses LCG if it's operating on an 8-byte state, so I'm trying to use the initstate method to set that.

I have the following code in my *glibc_random.c* file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "glibc_random.h"

void initialize()
{
    unsigned int seed = 1;
    char state[8];

    initstate(seed, state, sizeof(state));
}

long int call_glibc_random()
{
    long r = rand();
    return r;
}
```

And the following in the respective *glibc_random.h*:

```
void initialize();
long int call_glibc_random();
```

Code in python:

```
def test():
    glibc_random.initialize()
    number_of_initial_values = 10
    number_of_values_to_predict = 5
    initial_values = []

    for i in range(number_of_initial_values):
        initial_values.extend([glibc_random.call_glibc_random()])
```

When invoked in python, the code above keeps adding 12345 to my list of initial_values. However, when running the C code in [www.onlinegdb.com](http://www.onlinegdb.com) I get a more reasonable list of numbers (11035275900, 3774015750, etc.). I can only reproduce my problem in onlinegdb when I use `setstate(state)` after the call to `initstate(seed, state, sizeof(state))` in the `initialize()` method.

Can anybody suggest what is wrong here? I'm using swig and python2.7, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used `initstate` before but

```
void initialize()
{
    unsigned int seed = 1;
    char state[8];

    initstate(seed, state, sizeof(state));
}
```

seems wrong to me. `state` is a local variable of `initialize` and when the
function ends, the variable ceases to exit, so `rand()` might give you garbage
because it is trying to access a pointer that is no longer valid anymore.

You can declare `state` as `static` so that it doesn't cease to exist when
`initialize` end,

```
void initialize()
{
    unsigned int seed = 1;
    static char state[8];

    initstate(seed, state, sizeof(state));
}
```

or make `state` a global variable.

```
char state[8];

void initialize()
{
    unsigned int seed = 1;

    initstate(seed, state, sizeof(state));
}
```

Comment: Well, this seems to have solved the problem - a silly mistake of mine. Anyway, I still struggle to grasp the aftermath of this bug (like the program giving me 12345 all the time), but I guess I'll have to give it some more thought then. Thanks a lot!